# Creating web service from WSDL involving complex type without XSD

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I am creating a web service that reflects my WSDL. This WSDL contains complex type which I assume is because it has an XSD as well(which I don't have). The question is can I create a proxy class of this WSDL without XSD?

Answer (score 0):

Yes . Wsdl is used to create web service. Wsdl is form of xsd. If you use eclipse you will see the the methods and parameters while importing the wsdl itself

Comment: I am doing in .NET

Comment: use soapui to generate code in any language. https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/soap-code-generation.html